# How to use the same controller and same view multiple times on a page

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make a single page app where I want to load screens (partial views) via ajax. The problem is that the user want's to open the same screen multiple times (in tabs). I tried to load the controller code on initial load and loaded my screens (partial views) via AJAX. But the controller is already executed by the time the screen (partial view) is loaded.

I want to know how to make controller run after the partial view is loaded?

Or better yet, how to tackle this situation where i want to load the same view multiple time with different data/state?

Comment: any reason you're not using directive/component for this?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more how this will help? I want to load partial views on demand and the same view can appear multiple times. Also, a partial view hold a complete screen with grids, charts, and forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem I was facing. I am not sure if it is the best way to move forward but given the limited knowledge I have on AngularJS so far, this solution is my best bet. If anyone can come up with a better solution, I am all ears.

Instead of registering controller up front, I am registering the controller when the view is requested.

Also, I am appending a new div to the container where I want the view to appear. There is some jQuery on the page that hides other views and only shows the current view.

**Step 1**

Assigned `$controllerProvider.register` to a variable on App Scope

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
angular.module("myApp").config(function ($controllerProvider) {
                   myApp.registerCtrl = $controllerProvider.register;
               });
```

**Step 2**

In the function where I have to load the view dynamically, I did the following

```
$("#viewContainer").append($compile('<div ng-include="pageUrl"></div>')($scope));
```

The above line adds a div with `ng-include` directive. It also compiles the directive. The `pageUrl` is where I am keeping the url to the view I want to include.

**Step 3**

In the view file I have to load, I have include JavaScript file that holds my controller. The rest of the file contains simple HTML with directives. In the JS file, instead of creating the controller, I am registering the controller like

```
angular.module('myApp').registerCtrl("MyController", MyController);
```

I hope this is helpful to others.